# Microsoft excel formula to connect codes of smaller areas with those of the bigger ones and sum up their values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I am working with geographic information and I have bigger areas called Regso that concist of several smaller areas called Deso. The data I have is for the smaller Deso areas but I would like to transfer them to the bigger Regso areas by summing up their values. I have a spreadsheet which specifies which Deso areas are inside which Regso areas by connecting the name of the Regso to the code of the Deso. For ex:
Regso name + code, Deso codes

[image]

Then I have another spreadsheet with the values for the Deso areas. For ex:

| Deso | Women | Men | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0117C1130 | 5 | 10 | 15 |
| 0117C1140 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 0117C1150 | 10 | 2 | 12 |

The result Im looking for is for ex:

| Regso | Women | Men | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Berga | 17 | 14 | 31 |

So I am looking for one (or several) formula that will help me do this.

I now approximately what the formulae should do, but I'm not sure how to set them up.

One formula needs to look up the Deso code from the first spreadsheet in the range of the Deso column in my second spreadsheet and then look up and print out the value of women/men/total associated with that deso code. And the second formula needs to sum up the values of the Deso associated with each Regso. I don't know how to do this since Regso areas consist of 1-5 Deso areas, so its not very systematic.

Here are my data files:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10-bBwBXJnqEl33fGx7GfTp3y-ybrSm66/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105569512220761710053&rtpof=true&sd=true

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17vopfha4SPjzRK_hM1H1a01nedPXx1nT/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105569512220761710053&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! "I now approximately what the formulae should do, but I'm not sure how to set them up" Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1762273/edit) and include the formulae you tried. If you want people to assist you, you should show what you tried, and explain if you got any error/issue.

Comment: I havent tried any because as I said, i know approximately what the formula should do but not which one to use or how to set it up properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up the deso-regso connecting table like so and named it "desoregso":

[image]

Then I added an extra column to the deso table. The table should look like this and be called "desodata" for the function to work:

[image: deso]

The function which gets the "regso" for the "desodata" table is just a simple index-match.

```
=INDEX(desoregso[regso],MATCH([@deso],desoregso[deso],0),1)
```

Then just use a pivot table to make a summary of "desodata" like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! However, now the regso codes are listed under the regso names and the sums are written twice. How do I get the Regsokod in the column next to the Regso name?

Comment: try this function (just add another column to "desodata"): =INDEX(desoregso[regsokod],MATCH([@deso],desoregso[deso],0),1)

Comment: I meant how do I get the code next to the name in the pivot table. This function just adds a column with regso codes outside of the pivot table. But doesnt matter, I dont need both of them at the same time. Thank you :)

Comment: Ahh, I see. You would have to do what I described above. Then update the pivot table so that it includes the new column and then simply drag the "regsokod" into the "Rows" section of the pivot table schema.